# Pandas Dataframe: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to populate a matrix with values from a pandas dataframe, but get the error message: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
ampl.param['request'] = {
    (subjects[i], 1+p): request.iloc[p, i]
    for i in range(len(subjects))
    for p in range(len(students))
}
```

[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YghAo.png)

Comment: Um, why? `df.values` gives you a matrix

Comment: I am trying to populate a parameter in AMPL using the amplpy API. Basically, I want the same matrix, but through the ampl.param-command.

Comment: what is `ampl`? Can you add more to that code, it's difficult to understand whats going on

Answer (score 0):

loop over `range(1, len(subjects))` and try this  `(subjects[i-1], p): request.iloc[p-1, i-1]`

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. AMPL is an optimization software. I solved the problem by creating a list with the values from the pd dataframe (called request).

list = request.values.tolist()                                                            
ampl.param['request'] = {                                                                   
    (subjects[i], 1+p): list[i][p]
    for i in range(len(subjects))
    for p in range(len(students))
}